# PyQt5 - add AbstractButton to layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qabstractbutton

I'm making a Solitaire card game to practice OOP and PyQt5, and I'm having trouble adding a card, which inherits `QAbstractButton`, to a layout (`QGridLayout`, `QHBoxLayout`, or `QVBoxLayout`).  Here is part of the `Card` object:

```
class Card(QAbstractButton):    

    def __init__(self, rank=None, suit=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.visibility = False

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        if self.visibility == True:
            self.draw_card_front(painter)
        else:
            self.draw_card_back(painter)
        painter.end()

    def draw_card_back(self, painter):
        painter.setPen(COLOR_OUTLINE)
        painter.setBrush(COLOR_BACK)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, CARD_WIDTH-1, CARD_HEIGHT-1, 10, 10)

    def draw_card_front(self, painter):
        painter.setPen(COLOR_OUTLINE)
        painter.setBrush(COLOR_FRONT)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, CARD_WIDTH-1, CARD_HEIGHT-1, 10, 10)

        self.draw_rank(painter)
        self.draw_suit(painter)

    ...
```

And here is the game's class:

```
class Solitaire(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.card1 = Card(rank=1, suit=2, parent=self)
        self.card2 = Card(rank=1, suit=2, parent=self)

        grid.addWidget(self.card1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.card2, 1, 0)

        self.setWindowTitle('Yay')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 400)
        self.show()

    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    game = Solitaire()
    app.exec_()
```

When I run the program, the `Card` does not show up.  But if I don't use a layout, the `Card` shows up normally.  And if I try adding a `QPushButton` to a layout it works fine, too.  I feel like I'm missing something with the `parent` property, or perhaps I'm not overloading a function from `QAbstractButton` in the `Card` class.  Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#details):

> To subclass QAbstractButton, you must reimplement at least
>   **paintEvent()** to draw the button's outline and its text or pixmap. It
>   is generally advisable to reimplement **sizeHint()** as well, and
>   sometimes hitButton() (to determine whether a button press is within
>   the button). For buttons with more than two states (like tri-state
>   buttons), you will also have to reimplement checkStateSet() and
>   nextCheckState().

From the above we conclude that you must implement the `paintEvent()` method that is responsible for drawing the button, this depends on what you want to draw, and the `sizeHint()` method which is the size used by the layouts.

For example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Card(QAbstractButton):    

    def __init__(self, rank=None, suit=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.visibility = False

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100, 100)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        if self.visibility:
            self.draw_card_front(painter)
        else:
            self.draw_card_back(painter)

    ...

class Solitaire(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.card1 = Card(rank=1, suit=2, parent=self)
        self.card2 = Card(rank=1, suit=2, parent=self)

        grid.addWidget(self.card1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.card2, 1, 0)

        self.setWindowTitle('Yay')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 400)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    game = Solitaire()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Apologies, I did have that function present in `Card`.  I updated my question's code.

Comment: @calcium3000 I already update my answer, for your case it only implements sizeHint().

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you!  (I accidentally put `sizeHint()` in the `Solitaire` class at first - whoops!)